# Cannot find control with path: 'marketplace -> 1 -> marketplace'

Tags: angular, angular6

I have some amount of marketplace in array . I want to show that in textbox and if I want to edit and add new textbox I have to do. for that I did like this

```
 <div class="field_group" formArrayName="marketplace" >
    <div class="field_group_input last input-icon-plus" *ngFor="let markets of companyDetails.marketplace;let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">                          
  <input type="text" placeholder="Marketplace (eg: Euronext)" formControlName="marketplace" value="{{markets.marketplaceName}}">
   </div>
   </div>
```

and in Ts

```
companyDescFormInit() {
    this.companyDescForm = this._fb.group({
      marketplace : this._fb.array( [this.createMrktFields(true)] )
    })
  }
  get formData() { return <FormArray>this.companyDescForm.get('marketplace'); }

  createMrktFields(req:boolean = false): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
      marketplace: ['']
    });
  }
```

and error Im getting is

```
 Cannot find control with path: 'marketplace -> 0 -> marketplace'
    at _throwError (forms.js:1775)

Cannot find control with path: 'marketplace -> 1'
    at _throwError (forms.js:1775) 

Cannot find control with path: 'marketplace -> 1 -> marketplace'
    at _throwError (forms.js:1775)
```

Can anyone suggest me what mistake i Have done im getting same kind of error in one more place in my project . please assist me. Thanks

Comment: what is `companyDetails.marketplace`? Shouldn't you be iterating your formarray?

Comment: marketplace: [{marketplaceName: "ARR", idMarketplace: 19}, {marketplaceName: "DFG", idMarketplace: 20}]
0: {marketplaceName: "ARR", idMarketplace: 19}
idMarketplace: 19
marketplaceName: "ARR"
1: {marketplaceName: "DFG", idMarketplace: 20}
idMarketplace: 20
marketplaceName: "DFG"  i have this kind of array have to show this marketplace name value in textbox

Comment: I have list of marketplace in database when user loads i need to show values what already available and they can change text and update that time i have to pass in array of marketplace as id,marketplacename ., how can i achieve this?

Comment: well then you would want to iterate that array and create formgroups and stick those to the formarray.

Comment: so, what mistake I made in code?

Comment: you are not putting any of those values in your formarray.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199413/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-ajt82).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually put the values from your array to the formarray and then iterate that in the template. I have also renamed `formData` to `formArr`, since it makes more sense. Also in template, don't use `[value]` when you want to set a value to a formcontrol. Angular doesn't care about `[value]`, only what is put in the formcontrol as value.

So when you get your data to your array (getting it async or sync) iterate the array and create formgroups and push to the formarray. Here I added `Validators.required` to the name, since I assume you want it to be required:

```ts
this.companyDetails.marketPlace.forEach((x) => {
  this.formArr.push(this._fb.group({
    marketplaceName: [x.marketplaceName, [Validators.required]],
    idMarketplace: [x.idMarketplace]
  }))
})

// ....

get formArr() { return <FormArray>this.companyDescForm.get('marketplace'); }
```

Then iterate the formarray in template and display the name by `formControlName="marketplaceName"`:

```html
<div formArrayName="marketplace">
 <div *ngFor="let markets of formArr.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <input type="text" formControlName="marketplaceName">
 </div>
</div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yaxmae?file=src/app/app.component.html)**